# Awarding reps for excellent Questions / non-bounty Answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties

Sometimes it happens that I asked a question (without a bounty) and got the answer for it explained in an excellent way. Some people not only just answer the question , but  also :

i.  Share hell lot of information about the Ques/Answer

ii. They go one step ahead than just answering what was asked and explain the why part as well and not just how

and so on..

This happens many times when I am not even the one who asked the question, but was greatly surprised by the answer. Yes, I did up vote, but come on, sometimes the answers are just too good! Even the questions for that matter !

Thing is, I sometimes want to give my reps to others for their excellent answers/questions, even when it wasn't a bounty question itself.

Is it possible ? If not, what might be the possible rationale behind not having this feature ?

( Is the possible misuse of sharing one's reps with their friends an issue ? )

Comment: Aaaaaaa your heart is a Pacific Ocean :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can still add bounties on questions not asked by you. In fact, there is even a bounty reason for this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TatRV.png]

Note that the question has to be at least 2 days old. Once it is 2 days old, simply click the link that says "start a bounty" directly below the post.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and [the bounty privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) for more information.